# UIAlertController Presenting in Weird Location

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

Whenever I try to present this alert, it keeps appearing in some weird location.. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcMBF.png)

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                                                       message:@"Are you sure you want to logout?"
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
         handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:@"NO" forKey:@"auth"];
             [(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate changeRootViewController:[Login sharedLogin]];

         }]];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No"
                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                }]];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Did you use IQKeyboard(Or some other similar SDK)?

Comment: @Lumialxk nope! Are you suggesting that I should as a potential fix to this problem, or that if I had it might have been the problem itself?

Comment: I think you changed window frame to double width and height so it showed there. You can log this to check.

Comment: @Lumialxk oh my god.... I love you... Post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you changed window frame to double width and height so it showed there. You can log this to check.

Comment: I created my UIWindow with the nativeBounds and forgot to divide by the NativeScale.... :'(.. thank you again!